# Uploading custom user data into Database

Tags: php, database

As part of a bigger project, I'm building a reporting application which analyses business data. The aim is to have default datasets and also allow for users to upload their own datasets.

I'm building this in PHP however I'm not sure what the best database is to use. MySQL is great and usually my first pick, but this is application does not really require a relational database for the datasets. Datasets could be thousands of columns and millions of rows. Getting this to work MySql is quite a challenge.

I've seen HDF5 which seems like a good database though not very well supported from a web application point of view.

Do you have any other suggestions for a database that can store such large datasets?

P.S - I should clarify the reason for the title.... I need to be able to allow users to upload datasets. The only way with MySQL would be to allow for a table to be created each time the users uploads a dataset. Doesn't really sound very good.

Comment: Take a look at MongoDB it's NoSQL db and maybe something you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for your comment. After looking further into NoSQL databases which I have not really made use of in the past it does potentially look like a good way to go though I'll probably be using Cassandra instead. This database can store more than 2 billion columns. Thanks (and feel free to submit as answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into NoSQL databases. That sounds like what you are looking for. With NoSQL you don't have to create databases but store what ever and still be able to search the data fast.

Comment: Wow :) .... that's amazing stuff.... pity it's not available on shared hosting

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to create a sub table ( or something similar to this ) and store the custom fields in there:

Table name: **custom_fields**

```
+---------+----------------+----------+
| user_id | field name     | value    |
+---------+----------------+----------+
|      10 | favorite_sport | hockey   |
|      10 | favorite_food  | hot-dogs |
|      20 | sisters_name   | Ashley   |
+---------+----------------+----------+
```

And after this, just join the data together and show what you need.

Comment: And then also a row id would need to be included. An average dataset is 2,000 x 50,000 cells. That would be a lot of processing power to reconstruct that every time a user views that table and then still make queries on it. With consideration to speed wouldn't there be a better solution?

Comment: Well, if you want a user to be able to use custom fields, then it will always be lots of data + consider the options. A user can also create a field named `مجال عملي` that might mess up your site a lot too. So reconsider if you actually want to do it. If you do, then my suggestion is probably one of the best. But hey, there are always better solutions out there :)